# Java Finding a value in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have added few number into the arraylist . I would want to find the certain value from it.Example i have 4,4,9,9,18. I would like to find the value of 26. If 26 > largest value in the list it will display 18 and if value is 17 it will display 9, and if value is 5 it will display 4. Also is there another method to implement this search because liner search might be slow.

```
search value 26

    [4,4,9,9,18] display 18
    [20,20,29,29,4] display 20
    [28,28,28,1,10] display 28
```

if you have this list and search 26, it will output the first element. because the first element is <= than the value being search.

but current output is

> Value of value2 : 9

```
    public class Arraylist {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> aList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        aList.add(4);
        aList.add(4);
        aList.add(9);
        aList.add(9);
        aList.add(18);
        int value = 26;
        int value2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
            if (aList.get(i) <= value) {          
                if (i + 1 < aList.size()) {
                    value2 = aList.get(i);
                } else if(i > aList.size()) {
                    value2 = aList.get(i);

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Value of value2 : " + value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your logic. Are you looking for a place where a given value should be inserted into a sorted `ArrayList` to keep it sorted?

Comment: Another method could be to start search from the middle of the list, and check if the variable is higher or lower than value in the array, if lower then search backwards from this point and if higher search forwards.

Comment: So you've been asked to implement something that sounds almost like binary search...

Comment: If you array is always sorted then [**binary search**](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/Binary.htm) will be faster.

Comment: What if the value you are looking for is 3?

Comment: @PM 77, not sure if possible, but the arraylist is not always sorted , it can be add,[20 20 28 28 4]

Comment: @Jason Sperske, it will be 4

Comment: @user2822351 It won't be 4 according to your code, it will be 0 because you never enters the first if statement if value=3.

Comment: @Jason Sperske, Just to rectify the question a little, if value =< to the first number in the list, it will be that number.

Comment: @Jason Sperske the search suppose to search from [0]-[4] meaning from first number to the last, if value is bigger than all element, it will be the largest being displayed, if the value is =< than first element it will be that element too example [28,28,28,1,10] and you search 26 , a clearer picture

Comment: I think your examples are ill-defined. In particular for the value 26 you give [20,20,29,29,4] display 20, and [28,28,28,1,10] display 28. In the first case you display the number immediately less than 26, i.e. 20. In the second case you display the number immediately greater than 26, i.e. 28.

Comment: ` [28,28,28,1,10] display 28` while searching with `26` !! how come? it seems contradictory to your definition

Comment: @Sage, because when the first element is >= value, it wont go into the search anymore

Comment: If we have `[5, 4, 7, 8]` and we search with `6`, then ? is the result `4` ?

Comment: @user2822351, written a solution for you. works just like you want

Comment: Just curious, can you explain what this kind of search is for?

Comment: @Sage,[5, 4, 7, 8] and we search with 6 will be 5, because this will go thur the normal search unless u search for 4, it will be 5 also

Comment: @user2822351,  yes, i have given an answer by guessing that, please check below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written the code using an array. You can easily adopt it to `ArrayList`

```
int a[] = {28,28,28,1,10};
// int a[] = {20,20,29,29,4}; // other input of yours
// int a[] = {4,4,9,9,18};  

   int x = 26;

   int liVal = -1;
   for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++)
       if(x < a[i]) // if we met a value > x
       {
          if(liVal==-1) // if we could not find any largest value smaller than x
              liVal = a[i]; // return the value > x
          break;
       }
       else if(x > a[i]) // find the largest value smaller than x, 
       {
           if(liVal < a[i])
               liVal = a[i];
       }

System.out.println(liVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

A trivial and un-optimized version:

```
int value = 26 // or whatever parameter you get
int retVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i : list) {
  if (i <= value && i > retVal) {
    retVal = i;
  }
}
return retVal;
```

Comment: This won't handle the case where the value < min(list) because the if statement is never entered since i <= value is never true. In that case you will return Integer.MIN_VALUE instead of min(list).

Answer (score 0):

If the array is sorted you can use a variant of binary search.
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the biggest number in your array that is smaller or equal to `value`. I would do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
    if ( aList.get(i) <= value && aList.get(i) > value2) {
        value2 = aList.get(i);
    }
}
```

Also in your example, you do `value2 = 0`.  This is ok if you can guarante that the array only contains positive values.  Otherwise it would be better to use `value2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Finally, this code assume that the array is not guarantied to be sorted and that you will only need to search it once.  Otherwise, a [binary search](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) could be more performant.  Other answers on this question already show how to accomplish that.

Comment: @user2822351 : If your `ArrayList` is unsorted, then straight forward search could be your only option.

Comment: How is `value2` initialized?  What will happen if `value` is bigger than **all** elements of the list?

Comment: the search suppose to search from [0]-[4] meaning from first number to the last, if value is bigger than all element, it will be the largest being displayed, if the value is =< than first element it will be the largest element in the list example [28,28,28,1,10] and you search 26

Comment: Edited for clarity.  Indeed here I assumed that the list was not necessarily sorted.  I also did not originally commented on the initial value of the `value2` variable since the OP was concerned with the search.

Comment: I am more concerned of getting the correct display value and than the efficiency of the search

Answer (score 0):

Once you sort the list, [binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) in `Collections` will do the trick:

```
Collections.sort(aList)
int index = Collections.binarySearch(aList)
```

If `index` is nonnegative, the number was found in the list, and `index` is the position. If it is negative, it wasn't found, but `index` indicates where it would be if it were in the list.

And with `O(log n)` runtime for the search.

Comment: If you're only going to search a list once, the actual runtime is `O(n log n)` since you have to sort first.

Comment: I was just referring to the search since that is what the OP seemed concerned about. Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP's comments:

1. The list isn't sorted
2. if value < min return min
3. if value > max return max
4. if min <= value <= max return nearest val <= value

   ```
   public static int findValue(List<Integer> list, int value){
       int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, nearest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
       for(Integer v : list){
           if(v == value)
               return value;
           if(v > nearest && v < value)
               nearest = v;
           if(v < min)
               min = v;
       }
       return value < min ? min : nearest;
   }
   ```

As a side note, you don't need to keep track of the max because nearest = max if value > max(list).

Comment: I have added 3 example of list

Comment: In your examples the exact rules you are trying to convey are ambiguous. I think you meant the last example to display the number immediately < 26 which is 10. In that case this code will give you the correct answer.