# Searching address book for info

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I am trying to make an address book that prompts you enter the first, last, street address, city, State, and zip code for three people.

Then be able to search for any of the info the user inputs and then display all of the info for that person.

I have managed to get it to prompt the user for adding the info but I can't seem to figure out how to search the arraylist for the info.

```
for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
  {
    aBook.add(new YAAddressBook());
    aBook.get(count).addEntry();
    System.out.println();
  }

  int foundIndex = YAAddressBook.search(aBook);
  System.out.println();
  if (foundIndex > -1)
    aBook.get(foundIndex).display();
  System.out.println("Found");
  else
  System.out.println("No Entry Found");
}
}//end YoungAndrewChapter10


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class YAAddressBook
{
  private static String first;
  private static String last;
  private static String choice;
  private static String searchA;
  private static Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in);
  private String street;
  private String cityState;
  private String zip;
  private int answer = 0;

  public static int search(ArrayList<YAAddressBook> aBook)
  {
    System.out.print("Search Menu: \n1. Search First Name \n2. Search Last
      Name\n3.Search Street Address \n4.Search City, State \n5.Search Zip Code \n\n");

     System.out.print("Please Enter Field to Search: ");
    choice = keybd.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please Enter Value to Search For: ");
    searchA = keybd.nextLine();

    switch (choice)
    {
      case "1":
        break;
      case "2":
        break;
      case "3":
        break;
      case "4":
        break;
      case "5":
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return -2;
  }

  public void addEntry()
  {
    YAAddressBook aBook = new YAAddressBook();
    System.out.print("Please Enter First Name: ");
    first = keybd.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Last Name: ");
    last = keybd.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Street Address: ");
    street = keybd.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please Enter City, State: ");
    cityState = keybd.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please Enter Zip Code: ");
    zip = keybd.nextLine();
  }
}//end YAAdreesBook
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Finding a value in arraylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580855/java-finding-a-value-in-arraylist)

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580855/java-finding-a-value-in-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the field chosen, you would have to loop throughout all the arraylist until you find the correct item, for example if FirstName is chosen:

```
for (int i = 0; i< addressbook.size(); i++)
{
     if (addressbook.get(i).FirstName == "Tom" )
             return addressbook.get(i);
}
return null;
```

this will return the first element that matches the search, or `null` if nothing matches.